# TFS API to associate unit test with test case

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

I know I can use TFS api to query all test cases, but I can't figure out how to associate a unit test with a test case? Is that possible to do that?

For clarity, I'm looking to do what I'm currently doing in Test List Editor, programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a post on associating a unit test/coded ui test to a test case programmatically.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gautamg/archive/2012/01/01/how-to-associate-automation-programmatically.aspx

Mike